# How many ways are there to printf() and scanf() a float* variable?

Tags: c

I'm preparing for my graduation test and I have some questions regarding the c programming language. I will combine two of these questions which I have answers for, but I don't really understand them. The first question is select the correct expression that outputs the value of the *i*-th element of the array and these are the possible answers:
(note that the code for both questions is the same)

1. `printf("%f",B[i]);`
2. `printf("%f",&B[i]);`
3. `printf("%f",B+i);`
4. `printf("%p",*(B+i));`
5. `printf("%f",*(B+i));`

The second question is select the correct expression that inputs the value of the i-th element of the array

1. `scanf("%f", B[i]);`
2. `scanf("%f", B+i);`
3. `scanf("%p", B+i);`
4. `scanf("%f", &B[i]);`
5. `scanf("%f", *(B+i));`

I tried to compile and run a program that simulates these questions. The `scanf` part works for the answers 2-5 and all of the `printf`s print out a zero except the 4<sup>th</sup> one (of course after input).

```
float *B;
int n;
B=calloc(n,sizeof(float));
```

Comment: 2nd answer in first set is definitely incorrect. 3rd in the second set as well.

Comment: Read the documentation of the `printf`/`scanf` format specifiers `%f` and `%p` and what type you should supply as the corresponding argument. Compare this with the data types in the proposed function calls.

Comment: @EugeneSh. The first two answers are both incorrect.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to scan or print a `float`, not a `float *`.

Comment: It looks to be like 1. and 5. are correct in the first set; and 2. and 4. are correct in the second set.

Comment: Some of them will emit warnings - did you look at them?

Comment: The answers I have commented in my question are from a friend and not from the actual test people. @ThomasJager In my textbook B is declared as `float*`.

Comment: @DušanStojković `B` is a `float *`, but it's being used as an array of `float`. The elements of the array have type `float`, and that's what you're reading and writing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your understanding of which answers are correct are flawed.

To print a value of type `float` using `printf`, you need to use the `%f` format specifier and pass a value of type `float`.   To read a value of type `float` with `scanf`, you also use the `%f` format specifier but pass a value of type `float *`.

Regarding array indexing, the notation `A[N]` is exactly equivalent to `*(A + N)` and has the type of the array element, and `&A[N]` is exactly equivalent to `A + N` and has type pointer to array element.

Based on that, we have the following:

```
printf("%f",B[i]);    // Correct
printf("%f",&B[i]);   // Incorrect, passing a float *, expected float
printf("%f",B+i);     // Incorrect, passing a float *, expected float (same as prior)
printf("%p",*(B+i));  // Incorrect, %p is used to print a pointer (expects a void *)
printf("%f",*(B+i));  // Correct

scanf("%f", B[i]);    // Incorrect, passing a float, expected float *
scanf("%f", B+i);     // Correct
scanf("%p", B+i);     // Incorrect, %p is used to read a pointer (expects a void *)
scanf("%f", &B[i]);   // Correct
scanf("%f", *(B+i));  // Incorrect, passing a float, expected a float *
```

Answer (score 1):

**`float`**

There are 2 ways to `printf` a float and 1 way to `scanf` them.

```
printf("%f",  my_float);
printf("%lf", my_float); // works fine but bad style

scanf("%f",  &my_float);
```

(In the oldest C standard, `printf` didn't allow `%lf`)

---

**`float*`**

There is one way to `printf` the pointer itself:

```
printf("%p", ptr);
```

It doesn't make sense to read a pointer with `scanf`, but you can read to the memory pointed-at by the pointer `ptr` as:

```
scanf("%f",  ptr); // no & needed, it is already a pointer
```

---

Everything else from your examples doesn't make much sense. Printing an address is not printing a `float`. Applying various forms of arithmetic on the pointer such as `&B[i]` versus `*(B+i)` have nothing whatsoever to do with the the printing.

Comment: I agree with you that it doesn't make sense. These were just questions for an exam I'm preparing and I don't think someone might use this in practice. The test should just measure how much I understand c.